# Is there any way to disable browser back button using java code

Tags: java, javascript

Is there any way to disable browser back button using Java code? Javascript is not reliable in all browsers.

Comment: Leave my browser controls alone.

Comment: Actually JonK makes a really good point, who is going to use your application when it (in theory, not practise) will have control over the user's browser and possibly other applications. That would set off alarms in my head as malware. Is there a way: No. Should you do it: HELL NO. Your application should handle a 'back button' press itself and not worry about the user clicking it. If your code doesn't that's a flaw in it.

Comment: To add to the arguments that make this idea a bad one, [Java is just as easy to disable as Javascript](http://java.com/en/download/help/disable_browser.xml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your both assumptions are wrong.

1) No one can disable browser back button (*of course excluding the vendors* :)).

2) **Java** plays on server side. **Javascript** plays on client side.

You might want browser `onunload` function to prompt user.

@Derek did a demo for what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LZCj7/show/

Comment: Then how can i have a reliable code which can work in all browsers.

Comment: Proper way is to write it so you do not care if user use back button or not...

Comment: @user3244376 if your code breaks upon clicking on "Back" button in browser, then your code is not correct.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ JS can be disabled in browser, and it is preferred to have the version of the page working without JS, but typically there is only warning message that JS is turned off...

Comment: Java can be used on the client side, meanwhile JavaScript can be used on the client side. Your second assumption is inaccurate.

Comment: I have used  window.history.forward();
function preventBack() { window.history.forward(1); }                 to disable back button.But still request is going to previous page and new request is coming with same prameters and some wrong parameters which i dont want..

Comment: @user3244376 Can you please edit your post with, what is your problem if user clicks browser back button and the code you tried so far.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - And also for your first assumption, the back button *can* technically be disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/LZCj7/show/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yippie ..I can click a disabled button. :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Indeed, the button can still be clicked in the demo, however the functionality has been removed via JS.

Comment: I do not want users to go to previous page by clicking browser back button.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes. That is what I said as a solution. We cannot disable. But we can avoid leaving the page by prompting :). Agreed with that ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Uh, no. In my demo the button is completely disabled.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Disable means, you can't click. Bypassing it's functionality is another thing.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I have tested in IE 8 your code is not working.

Comment: If that's the definition of disable you are working with then there's no way to make the button unclickable. You can only remove it's functionality via js.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yes. That is what I mean. And also thanks for that demo. Going to include that.

Comment: @user3244376 It's not supposed to work in all browsers (it's just a proof of concept ;) and yes, although technically you can "disable" the button, don't do it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60465/discussion-on-answer-by-ss--is-there-any-way-to-disable-browser-back-but).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Yes (for certain definitions of disable).

You are completely free to exercise whatever forms of navigation control on your website, and create a series of once-only urls, which must be accessed in a specific order, thus rendering the back button useless. (you could even cause re-visiting these urls to return to a pre-defined homepage)

Common misconceptions:

- You can use javascript to control a browser on a client. - You can't, there's no two ways about it, the javascript is out of your control and can be modified by a 7year-old (this is a conservative estimate based on experience, not expectation.),
- Preventing backwards navigation is always hacky and/or bad. Certain things should really attempt to do this better - Ever done an online quiz, or memory game?

Solution:
*please note this will not disable the button, and will instead invalidate requests made to a 'previous' url*

Include a key in every request (which changes for every subsequent request), and is associated with the HttpSession, this could then be included in form submission - bear in mind, someone who knows what they're doing can still extract this and use it to travel backwards, so it is also worthwhile ensuring that your key can only be used for a specific subset of pages from your entire site (those allowed). Many easy ways to do this, personally I am a fan of primes and hashes.

*also note, refreshing a page with this could cause you grief if you have not considered your desired behaviour. Do so, and implement it.*

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try to disable the back button, as your website shouldn't extend beyond the limits of the viewport, but you should rather **try to change your approach**. I'm pretty sure that what you want to acheive can be done in another way! Why don't you tell us more about it?

JavaScript was designed to act on DOM elements, and unfortunately, the back button isn't part of them. Also, unlike what you think, JavaScript is reliable, and although the result may slightly vary from one browser to another, there are some libraries that are able to tackle this problem.

As for Java, you might be thinking of applets... But it's still not the right way to go, and in terms of cross-browser compatibility, the situation is much worse than it is with JavaScript.

So, in a nutshell, YES, there might be some workarounds to prevent the use of the back button, but NO, you should'nt try to do it, because it's considered a bad practice.

**EDIT:**

Here is a snippet of JavaScript (not Java) ode that can prevent the previous page from loading:

```
<script>
function preventBackButton(){window.history.forward();}
setTimeout("preventBackButton()", 0);
window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

But remember, this is NOT a good practice. You should NOT use it. Why don't you tell us what you want to achieve so we can help you do it the right way?

Comment: What are the libraries that can tackle back button event.

Comment: Your approach is definitely wrong, you shouldn't forbid the user from using the back button, but rather handle the event that a user might click on the back button...