Clear-Site-Data header doesn't seem to work on Java Servlet HttpServletResponse Object
It is my first time encountering the problem where if I have a Web App with login, and the user logs out and then presses the back button in the browser, he can still access the page form cache.
I know there are multiple ways of solving this problem, so I don't need a thousand different suggestions, I would like to know why my solution with Clear-Site-Data header doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
@WebServlet("/LogoutServlet")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        resp.addHeader("Clear-Site-Data", "cache");
        resp.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
}

Instead of this line resp.addHeader("Clear-Site-Data", "cache");
I also tried this resp.addHeader("Clear-Site-Data", "*");
I also tried all of the above with response.setHeader()
And I tried this on login.jsp <meta http-equiv="Clear-Site-Data" content="cache">
And also: <meta http-equiv="Clear-Site-Data" content="*">
I really expected one of theese to prevent going back to secure pages with back button in browser (chrome) but none of them worked. Please tell me why, and how to fix, thank you in advance.

I believe you want to disable back button default behaviour "to prevent going back in browser" because manipulating a cache doesn't protect you from dysplaing a page after logout. This can be done the following  https://stackoverflow.com/q/25624458/573032

@RomanC I don't want to disable the back button. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my explanation, the pages of the project are protected by a filter.  Whenever a client tries to access a page the filter checks for authentication first, and doesn't allow the client access to the page unless a login already happened,  verification for the filter is stored in session attribute. when the logout servlet is called the session is invalidated as you can see from my code. This means reloading the previous page from the server would be preventetd by the filter.  But... the pages will  load from cache...

@RomanC I know i can fix this by preventing cache-ing theese pages alltogether, but I didn't want to do that. I'm looking for a solution where all the secure pages can still use cache the back button is also enabled. but when logout happens all cache is disposed, and thus when back button is pressed the page has to reload from server and access is denied by the filter. This is the idea.

If you know how to fix this "by preventing cache-ing theese pages alltogether", so why you didn't add this to the question? Why you didn't add a security filter? Because you added a wrong header to the response and the page is returned from the cache after you redirected?
